How to disable depthCulling of ViewRenderable in ARCore Sceneform
I have an ARCore scene with a node of ModelRenderable and another node of ViewRenderable. e.g.
val cubeRenderable = ShapeFactory.makeCube(Vector3(1f, 1f, 1f), Vector3.zero(), material)
val textRenderable = ViewRenderable.builder().setView(this,R.layout.view_ar_text).build().await()
val cubeNode = Node().apply {
    renderable = cubeRenderable
    setParent(arSceneView!!.scene)
}
val textNode = Node().apply{
    renderable = textRenderable
    setParent(arSceneView!!.scene)
}

I want the ViewRenderable node always render on top without getting blocked, even though its spatial position is behind the ModelRenderable view when viewed from the camera. I did some searching and found the depthCulling property, my intuition is to set it to false for the material of the ViewRenderable
I tried
textRenderable.material.setBoolean("depthCulling",false)

Unfortunately this dosen't seem to have any effect. textNode is still blockable by cubeNode
